# Maxlength for Div and Span elements

Tags: html, maxlength

How to set max length for Span and Div elements ?

Answer (score 4):

There are the

```
max-height / max-width
```

CSS properties that will limit the width for block level elements (i.e. not `span`s). [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_max-width.asp)

Note that they are [not supported by IE 6](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/width.html).

Answer (score 3):

`input` and `textarea` html tags have maxlength attribute but `div` and `span` element don't have. To restrict user from entering more characters compare to maxlength in span or div element, you can do following using `javascript` and `jquery`:

You can add `keydown` event listener on `div` or `span` element and add following functions in event listener.

1: Using javascript `substring` method.

```
$("#div-element").on("keydown", function () {
    var value = $("#div-element").val();
    if (value.length > maxlength) {
        $("#div-element").val(value.substring(0, maxlength));
    }
}());
```

2: Returning `false` on event.

```
$("#div-element").on("keydown", function () {
    var value = $("#div-element").val();
    if (value.length > maxlength) {
        return false;
    }
}());
```

These both have followup issues which should be handled as well ie `substring` method change the cursor position, in `keydown` method we need to check which key is pressed, otherwise it return false even on backspace or delete key.

Answer (score 2):

When the word contained is too large the div or span may overflow:

```
<div style="width: 80px; overflow: hidden;" >hhhhhhheeeeeellllllllllooooo</div>
```

- You can wrap a span with a div. It will cut the content if there are no spaces in the text but it will prevent overflow from happening.

If long words are the problem a CSS3 solution could be:

> style="width: 80; word-wrap: break-word;"

Answer (score 0):

If you mesn width, then use css width properties:

```
<div style='max-width:100px'>Content</div>
<span style='max-width:100px; display:block;'>Content</span>
```

If you really mean length of content, You can't, in HTML. You need to use a piece of javascript to do this. Take a look at JQuery, it's really easy to do. It will boil down to something like:

```
$('#yourDivId').html().length
```

Comment: I don't get the `.length` bit. What is this supposed to do? Isn't that the character length of the HTML string?

Comment: Pekka: yes :P At first read it seemed to me he was trying to get the length of the html content. Then I realized he probably meant width...

Comment: well, on the other hand, he *is* talking about `maxlength`. That could be a typo or a reference to the form element attribute. We'll see when he comments.

Answer (score 0):

You mean max width?

```
max-width: ??px;
```